Combine two overlapping rasters by adding the values in QGIS
In QGIS I have a cost function raster, where I want to add multiple other costs provided by different raster layers.
Example:
The cost of Raster 2 (which has fixed values of 1000) has to be added to Raster 1, so that when one overlapping value point was 3.5 beforehand it should be 1003.5 afterwards. Where no overlap is given, the original value should stay.
Raster 1 
Raster 2 
The idea is to make lakes an unpassable area for my least-cost-path algorithm.

Since the question was asked, I tried using the Raster Calculator but it does not seem to do the trick, since the numbers which are only postitive before afterwards go into the negative. I used followoing formula:
"Layer1" + "Layer2".
Both layers have the same CRS. Maybe my problem is the usage of the raster calculator?


what have you tried with the raster calculator?

Thank you I tried that and I amended my question to include my trys with the raster caluclator. Maybe I use it wrong?

Check what the no-data value is for your raster - I suspect it's a negative number an that's why you're getting a negative sum. You either need to add an if-clause to check for no-data, or change the no-data value to 0.

As commented by Llaves:

Check what the no-data value is for your raster - I suspect it's a
negative number an that's why you're getting a negative sum. You
either need to add an if-clause to check for no-data, or change the
no-data value to 0.

Changing the no-data value to 0 did the trick.
